# Exception Stack Trace difference between Debug and Release mode

Tags: c#

The code below generates different exception stack trace in both debug and release mode:

```
static class ET
{
    public static void E1()
    {
        throw new Exception("E1");
    }
    public static void E2()
    {
        try
        {
            E1();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;

        }
    }

    public static void Entry()
    {
        try
        {

            E2();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {           
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Result in Debug Mode:

> at ET.E1() in D:\myStudio\CSharp\CSharp4.0\MyCSharp\ExceptionHandling.cs:line 47
>
> at ET.E2() in D:\myStudio\CSharp\CSharp4.0\MyCSharp\ExceptionHandling.cs:line 58
>
> at ET.Entry() in D:\myStudio\CSharp\CSharp4.0\MyCSharp\ExceptionHandling.cs:line 68

Result in Release Mode:

> at ET.E2() in D:\myStudio\CSharp\CSharp4.0\MyCSharp\ExceptionHandling.cs:line 55
>
> at ET.Entry() in D:\myStudio\CSharp\CSharp4.0\MyCSharp\ExceptionHandling.cs:line 68

Please note that the first line from the result in Release mode is missing. How to return the offending line in release mode.

Comment: `E1` has been inlined into `E2` - a useful optimization usually, but it does mean some methods will be missing from stack trace.

Comment: I belive that this is working as intended. The compiler is free to inline methods when optimizing for release builds, in which case the original method simply is not part of the created assembly. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: Thanks! I also thought it is inline. Using [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] is the Only way to prevent that, I think.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are probably seeing the result of [inlining](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/02/19/inlining-yes-it-happens.aspx).  When you compile in debug mode, inlining is always turned off (so that debugging makes sense).  When you compile in release mode, the compiler will remove certain methods (subject to [a lot of rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973858.aspx#highperfmanagedapps_topic10)) and insert their content into all of the call sites.  This improves the overall performance of those methods by removing the method call overhead.

Comment: Thanks! Using [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] is the Only way to prevent that, I think.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that you are probably taking a performance hit doing that.  How big of a hit is probably debatable.

Comment: But tools like log4net should be able to report the offending line as if it is in debug mode, even it is running in release mode. If it is the case, how does it achieve that is interesting.

Comment: Either they won't show the inlined method, or the call to l4n will prevent the method from inlining.  Without looking at it, I suspect that this latter one is actually quite likely.